# FACEBOOK API CALL - PHP SDK FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

trying to get every post and comment from a facebook page, I made this function that should go through the pagination:

```
$req = $facebook->api("/" . $pagename . "/?fields=posts.fields(message,link,created_time,shares,likes,comments)");

function parcours_arbre($ab)
{
  GLOBAL $facebook;
  GLOBAL $pagename;
  $next = create_request($ab['posts']['paging']['next']);
  $next_req = $facebook->api($pagename.$next);
  $ab_next = $next_req['data'];
  $prev = create_request($ab['posts']['paging']['previous']);
  $prev_req = $facebook->api($prev);
  $ab_prev = $prev_req['data'];
  if (empty($ab)) {
    display_results($ab['posts']['data']);
  } else {
    parcours_arbre($ab_next);
    parcours_arbre($ab_prev);
  }
}
```

I unfortunately get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: posts in /form.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /utils.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /utils.php on line 20

Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. thrown in /sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1271
```

Any idea how i could avoid it or what is going on? Would this go away if i use the "until" statement in my api request?
Thanks a lot,

Comment: you may have errors in form, utils php files check them properly

Comment: I solved the three Notice: statements.
Now I just have this left:
Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: No node specified thrown in /sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain each error

- the variable $ab which is an argument to the function, does not have a "posts" index. You should try to `var_dump` this variable so you can see what it actually looks like.
- same as above
- same as above
- the `api` function takes 3. The path which should just be `@pagename`. The method ("GET" or "POST") most likely POST because GET is causing an error. The parameters, which should be array("fields" => "posts.fields(message,link,created_time,shares,likes,comments)")

I noticed that for next you have the code

```
$next_req = $facebook->api($pagename.$next);
```

but for previous you have

```
$prev_req = $facebook->api($prev);
```

Might want to look into this.

Comment: in the parcours_arbre function, I try to explore the paging of the api response. I already take care of the first page $req. Then I need to explore the previous and next pages of results. It's like exploring a binary tree but you do not know how deep you have to go.

Comment: @user2162058 can you show me an example url? Not coded, just a general url you would navigate to using php.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/care4adrink for example. I need to put into a CSV file all posts and comments on a facebook fan page.

Comment: Apparently, it turns out that a recursive api call to the Facebook Api is not working very much.

Comment: @BertrandDubaut made an edit, i feel like this may be the problem